# Need to know how to compare 3 columns and print true or false

Tags: excel-formula

I have ran into a bit of issue.

Issue:

I have 3 columns A,B,and C. I am trying to compare column A,B,and C. if column B and C are the same and A is not than I want excel to put in to column D a value of true. If B and C are not the same than just ignore and delete that row if possible if not just leave the cell blank. and if A,B, and C all are same also ignore and delete. I hope it makes sense

Visual:

```
A   B   C   D
12  3   3   TRUE
4   4   4   
15  10  15  
3   2   2   TRUE
1   1   1
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With cell formula you can't do operations like deleting rows - that would require VBA triggered by some action, e.g. a button.

However the following should give you your blank option:

```
=IF(B1=C1,IF(A1=C1,"",TRUE),"")
```

Comment: Thank you it worked =). I just hid the blank rows using Filter

Answer (score 0):

try this

=IF(AND(A1=condition1, B1=condition2, C1=condition3), TRUE, FALSE)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).